# How to write TextView over an ImageView at a specific position in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to combine TextView and ImageView and want to place the TextViews at the center of both the circles in the image but somehow I haven't been able to figure out a solution that will work across different kind of devices.
This is the image I'm trying to use:

[image]

This is what I've tried till now. I've put both the imageview and the textview in a framelayout and then tried to adjust the textview by using linearlayouts and layout weights.
`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="80">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_pic"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="85"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="@string/text1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="50sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="@string/text2"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="15">

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/text3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="40">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="@string/tv3"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="50sp"
                    android:text="000"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>`
```

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` and put your image and textViews in it and use **drag drop** of your IDE to put it at the desired position.

Comment: this is where things like wrap_content and match_parent wont work try using hardcoded values like 50 dp for images then you can place the textview at 25 dp to get the desired result

Comment: I've already tried these. They don't solve the problem of being functional across a range of devices

Comment: Hi @RaghavKukreja, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout to achieve this as

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="<your_drawable>"/>
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This will position the textview in the center of the complete image. I'm trying to position two textviews at the center of both the circles respectively.